# registration forms and foreign keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ok, I'm missing something obvious here, but here goes:

I created a user with Devise

I created a `user_goals` model with four goals

I created a `user_goal_id` field in the users table.

In my user registration form I want to present a `collection_select` of the four possible goals, and put the id of the selected goal into the users table when the user is created.

I can't figure out how to do this. Specifically, I can't figure out how to write the `user_goals` selected id to the `user_goal_id` field in the users table.

EDIT:

Do I need to create a user_goals controller, or can I just put the controller logic in the users_controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out this is really simple. You don't need to do any logic in the controller or model. You just do the following in the registration form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

The above line is just the `form_for` that creates a form. the scaffold, or in this case, Devise will create this. Remember the `do |f|` at the end.

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= f.label :Whats_your_goal? %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :user_goal_id, UserGoals.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => ""}%>
```

The first line is just the label for the field

The second line is the drop down. `f.collection_select` tells your form generator that this is going to be a drop down list of options.

`:user_goal_id` is the name of the field in the users table where I want to record the `foreign key` of the goal from the `user_goals` table.

`UserGoals.all` is the name of database table I want the drop down list to populate from. `.all` says I want all of the items from that database table

I believe `:id,` pulls the items by their database ID number or primary key, and `:name` says give me the name column of the table, as opposed to description, or something.

Finally, `{ :include_blank => "" }` just creates a blank space at the top of the drop down, so there isn't a default selection. You can also put a message between the `""` if you want.

I had a hard time finding a simple explanation of this, probably since it's so basic. Hopefully someone else will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please ask precise question, this is too general. Give some parts of your code and ask something precise, if you don't really understand what you are asking for, the persons that try to answer you won't understand neither. Please check rails guides, there is a nice chapter on ActiveRecord relation (which is wrapping the foreign keys) and do some tutotials. Once you understand how it works, if you need a precise help on a error message or a piece of code, please come back and ask your question, you'll have quick answer I'm sure :)

Comment: Thanks, this is actually exactly the kind of help I was looking for. I needed Active Record Association basics rails guide.

Comment: Right here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and you have 8 pages of video here (90% of them are free) http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=2